Problem with pg_cron on Postgress CloudSql Google
I have a problem with scheduling jobs using the postgress pg_cron extension on Google's db clous sql. In summary I have to schedule a job every Tuesday at 2pm (0 14 * * 2). This schedule doesn't work correctly because if I put "2" or "Thu" as the day of the week it doesn't work while if I put "3" it works. It's basically as if the cron travels one day ahead of my timezone. I checked and my timezone is set correctly on the db with Europe/Rome.
Do you have any advice on how to solve it? I also updated pg_cron to version 1.6.
Thanks
Marco
Today is Tuesday and therefore this schedule (0 14 * * 2) must run but it doesn't work. If I put "3" (0 14 * * 3), like it's Wednesday, it works.

Check your week definition. It appears to not be the ISO and it has the first day of the week as Sunday instead of Monday. If so then Tuesday is day 3. Is this consistent.
